# Multi-indexed series into DataFrame and reformat

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a correlation matrix of stock returns in a Pandas DataFrame and I want to extract the top/bottom 10 correlated pairs from the matrix.

Sample DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(5,30,size=500)
df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape((50,10)))
corr = df.corr()
```

This is my function to get the top/bottom 10 correlated pairs by 1) first returning a multi-indexed series (high) for highest correlated pairs, and then 2) unstacking back into a DataFrame (high_df):

```
def get_rankings(corr_matrix):

    #the matrix is symmetric so we need to extract upper triangle matrix without diagonal (k = 1)
    ranked_corr = (corr_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_matrix.shape), k=1).astype(np.bool))
                    .stack()
                    .sort_values(ascending=False))

    high = ranked_corr[:10]
    
    high_df = high.unstack().fillna("")
    
    return high_df

get_rankings(corr)
```

My current DF output looks something like this:

```
    6   4   5   7   8   3   9
3   0.359           0.198           
1       0.275                   
4           0.257               
2                   0.176   0.154   
0   0.153                   0.164   
5   0.156
```

But I want it to look this in either 2/3 columns:

```
ID1 ID2 Corr
0   9   0.304471
2   8   0.271009
2   3   0.147702
7   9   0.146176
0   7   0.144549
7   8   0.111888
4   6   0.098619
1   7   0.092338
1   4   0.09091
3   6   0.079688
```

It needs to be in a DataFrame so I can pass it to a grid widget, which only accepts DataFrames. Can anyone help me rehash the shape of the unstacked DF?

Comment: `high.unstack().fillna("").reset_index()`.

Comment: That doesn't work as it's still in a 'matrix format' not a single column of correlations.

Comment: I dont understand, didn't you already have it without `reset_index()`?

Comment: Just updated the post to be more clear. Basically reset index just added an extra column on the front. But I want to rehash the 'matrix' format and just show the pairs in 1/2 columns and then correlation of those pairs in next column. I think pivot could do it but I dont know how to deal with the multi-index.